# Direct image of Lagrangian subspaces of the co-tangent bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, d-modules, lagrangian-submanifolds

Let $p:X \to Y$  be a map of smooth algebraic varieties.
Let $C \subset T^* X$ be a (locally closed) submanifold. Denote by $p_*(C) \subset T^* Y$   the following set:

$$ \{(y,v) \in T^*(Y)\mid\exists x \in p^{-1}(y) \text{ with } (x,(d_x(p))^*(v)) \in C \}.$$

This operation can describe (to some extent) what happens to the singular support of a D-module when one takes its direct image.

My question is: when can one claim that $p_*$ of a (conic) Lagrangian manifold is Lagrangian? I heard it is not true in general. Is it true when $p$ is proper? What are the counter examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a negative answer from Thomas Bitoun:

*Malgrange, Bernard*, [**Sur les images directes de ${\mathcal D}$-modules**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01168827), Manuscr. Math. 50, 49–71 (1985). [Zbl 0572.32014](https://zbmath.org/0572.32014).

It is at the very end of the paper, (6.3) page 23 of the electronic
version. It is in French and Malgrange attributes the example to
Kashiwara.